# How to change the position of Yii bootstrap CSS register?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using Yii Bootstrap 2.2 and Yii 1.1.10. I'm using also the yii-bootstrap extension from http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap in my site. I have used similar configuration in other sites, and in that case, the Bootstrap CSS is loaded after the CSS declared in the main layout.

But in this case, the Bootstrap CSS is loaded on top of the head tag, before any other CSS. This causes my nice Boostrap buttons to show with rare colors.

The question is, is there any way to change the order of loading this Bootstrap extension in order to load AFTER my custom classes in header like did it before?

The bootstrap is loading well, with no JS errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Firtst:  boostrap.php following command this function

```
public function registerYiiCss() {Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($this->getAssetsUrl().'/css/bootstrap-yii.css');}
```

> second: views/layout/main.php

```
$cssUrl = Yii::app()->boostrap->getAssetsUrl().'/css/bootstrap-yii.css');
```

the above cssUrl you can put below head tag

Answer (score 1):

You must add your css code before the `<title>...</title>` tags and it will be loaded before other registered files...

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
<title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
...
</head>
```